# Can I display one to many results in results table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for `person` and a table for `language`. Each person can speak up to 4 languages. My client wants to search for people that can speak, for instance `Spanish`.

My problem is that the results table currently won't have a column called `Language` because they will speak more than one. I could display just the first one, but it will be misleading to hide the other languages that they speak.

The table could have a column for each language, and fill in `NULL` if they don't have all 4 languages, i.e.:

```
Language 1
Language 2
Language 3
Language 4
```

But this seems very sloppy.

I have considered listing all of the languages in a single column, using a comma separated list, but this is know good for sorting the column alphabetically.

Currently, I am having to tell my client that the results table can only show columns where the person has one of them (1 to 1), i.e. `name`, `location`, native language etc. Only when the client clicks on that person, can it reveal all of their languages.

Does anyone know if there is a common way to solve this? Hope this makes sense

I do have an association table. The problem is that my search will return

joe bloggs, gotham city, spanish

then

joe bloggs, gotham city, french

on the next row - but then the same person is listed twice in the table. When I restrict it to one entry per name, I just get "joe bloggs, gotham city, spanish". Now I don't know that he also speaks french. Is this clearer?

Comment: What exactly is your table structure, and what is your query? Do you want a result set of one line with all the person's languages?

Comment: please check how one marks an answer. Many people won't answer your questions in the future if you don't have a good answer rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought about this some more, it seems that you have the following options

1. Use the simple join/link/association table that both Christophe and I suggested, then massage the data in the program which calls the SQL. This is the simplest route to take.
2. Maintain a comma delimited list of languages along with the join table. The join table will allow you to answer queries such as 'who speaks Spanish', whereas the list will enable you to print out a list of languages per person. Maintaining this list will be a problem.
3. Use the 'dedicated field per language' approach of Ravindra; every time you need a new language, you will have to change the field structure, thus this approach is very much not recommended.
4. Use a cross tab query; this is quite hard to do and depends on which flavour of SQL you are using. Look at this article [creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/).

In my option, option 1 is the best and easiest. SQL is great at what it does and terrible at what it doesn't do, so it's best to take the best parts of SQL and surround them with the best parts of a declarative language.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have gone with option 1 - and am not going to have a column in the results table where the person can have more than one item for that column. It is kind of redundant anyway - if my client filters her search down to spanish speakers, we know that all returned results can speak spanish, so no need for a column in the results table whereby every row will display "Spanish". At least, this is how I have "sold" my solution to the client

Answer (score 1):

You should have a join table which contains two fields: person and language. There should be one row per person per language, so if one person speaks four languages, there would be four rows for this user.

The primary key for this table would comprise both fields.

Then to get a list of which people speak Spanish, you would need a query like

```
select people.name
from people inner join p2l
on people.id = p2l.person
inner join languages
on p2l.language = languages.id
where languages.name = 'Spanish'
```

And a list of all people who speak a language

```
select people.name, languages.name
from people inner join p2l
on people.id = p2l.person
inner join languages
on p2l.language = languages.id
```

And now a list of all people, whether they speak a language or not

```
select people.name, languages.name
from people left join p2l
on people.id = p2l.person
inner join languages
on p2l.language = languages.id
```

Comment: Hi. I do have this. See the extra text I have added to my original question. The problem comes when NO language is defined in the search criteria - it will return all of their languages, and end up with 4 entries for that person in the results table. Sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: If a person speaks no languages then there will be no rows in the p2l table. In this case, you need a 'left join' instead of an 'inner join'

Answer (score 0):

So the traditional way to solve this is to create something called an association table, which has foreign keys to both the person and language tables. This lets you add an arbitrary number of languages (including zero). Then you can join accross these tables to find all users speaking a specific language.

This may help with how to structure databases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form
There's higher normal forms, but this will help you solve your current problem.

Comment: Please see my additional comment I've added to the question

Comment: Then can't you process the results from your query on the server side? It really can't be done at the database layer without a lot of pain.

Comment: I can, I'm just wondering if there is an elegant way of displaying the results of a 1 to many relationship where more than 1 result is returned. I guess I should have put that in my initial question. A way that avoids having duplicate rows for each person

Comment: You could use a correlated subquery to fetch the 4 languages known by a person, ordered alphabetically, filling in nulls for extra spots. But it wouldn't be performant, and it would be painful to write.

Comment: Yes I suspected this - that there wasn't an elegant solution. I shall have to not display columns where a person can have more than one. It just seems like such a common problem that there would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

create two table
person having cloumns- `person_id,person_name & more` if u want.
create another table -Language having columns-`person_id,lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4`
make `person_id as foreign key`
now when u want to access languages, just fetch them by compairing person_id

```
 SELECT p.person_id
FROM person p, language l
WHERE p.person_id = l.person_id;
```

Comment: What happens when a new language has to be added? This is a very inflexible solution and should be avoided at all costs. This is a violation of first normal form - no repeating groups.

Comment: @Ravindra bagaleji: aare dhanyawad kasala...eka marathi manasa la downvote kelela mi baghu shakat nahi...